# How to cache or preload SKLabelNode font in spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I want to load the font once and use it for the other sklabel nodes

```
let originalLabel: SKLabelNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "fontName");
```

and later

```
var labelNode = originalLabel;
var labelNodeSecond = originalLabel;
```

but that gives the following error

**Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: SKLabelNode**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the font once by initializing an `UIFont`:

```
let yourFont = UIFont(name: "yourfontName", size: 17)

var firstLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: yourFont?.fontName) 
var secondLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: yourFont?.fontName)
```

That way, you only set the font once and the SKLabelNodes don't have to load it by themself.

Comment: Thanks Christian this little make the game 40x faster, because I am creating 8 sklabelnodes and it was very slow even the name of the font is right! Once again thanks for the help